# SQL Server : search for all columns with NULL value across database

Tags: sql-server, null

I have a database with ~420 tables in it. All the tables have Audit columns: field1, field2, field3.

How do I write a query to check if there are any NULL values in any of these audit columns across the entire database?

Comment: Retrieve the database metadata and then use dynamic SQL. The metadata tells you the full list of tables & columns. Then use dynamic SQL to assemble custom SQL statements for each table, such as `select count(case when field1 is null then 1 end) as f1 from table1`.

Comment: Different DBMS store meta-data about the tables in different ways.  So, which DBMS are you using?  SQL Server, RedShift, Oracle, MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, etc, etc, etc?

Comment: It's a SQL server DB

Comment: if the column is nullable, you should assume there is a null value, no? or at least there could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should do a trick for you, play around if you need different output.

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = ''
DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(100)

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''

    -- check tables
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0

    )

    -- check if above table has columns we want to check
    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)      
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        -- insert into temp table if column value is null
        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            INSERT INTO #Results EXEC('SELECT DISTINCT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' IS NULL ')
    END   
END

 -- return results
SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

-- drop temp table
DROP TABLE #Results
```